# What sites can be added to toast?

Tags: package-management, perl

I am using [toast - packageless package manager](http://www.toastball.net/toast/) because I have no root access. One of the sites toast looks up packages is the now defuct site freshmeat.net.

I tried to add http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe as possible source but the URL format does not work.

What sites can be easily added to toast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Package Manager is now a defunct PerlScript.  I Quote:

> What, you're afraid to run it? Don't worry. It's harmless. In fact it
>   doesn't do anything anymore. It used to do something (5 points if you
>   can tell me what), but then bitrot set in. There's a moral to this
>   story (worth 10 points).

Taken from: [ToastBall.net](http://www.toastball.net/)

Please note that I did not institute the points system here, but in essence am answering the 5 point question.

---

I believe the bitrot the author is referring to is this bit at freshmeat(Quote):

> - The Freecode site has been moved to a static state effective June 18,    2014 due to low traffic levels and so that folks will focus on
>     more    useful endeavors than site upkeep.
> - The site contents have been retained in this static state as a    continued path to access the linked software, much of which is on
>     self-hosted servers and would be difficult to find otherwise.

See the full entry at [About Freecode](http://freecode.com/about)

---

### Reasoning

Notice the last official package for download from the official developer's site, version 1.486 dated 15-Jul-2012, and the option contained in the man page:

**--findsites=SITELIST**

> Set the list of web sites or other locations searched by toast find
>   for packages that have not already been added. SITELIST is a
>   space-separated list of URLs and/or special words taken from the
>   following list: freshmeat, googlecode, sourceforge, gnu, cpan, or all
>   (which stands for all of the preceding words in the order given). The
>   * character will be replaced by the name of the package to find wherever it occurs. If you want a literal * character, too bad.
>   Default: all.

Notice that the default list contains freshmeat, and gnu.  Under normal circumstances gnu shoud never disappear, as all linuxes are derived from GNU Software, plus the GNU Software Foundation is a legal entity.  Freshmeat on the other hand was a hosting site for projects, most of which are hosted on SourceForge or GitHub now.  The developer on the other hand has hardcoded that list somewhere in his perl script, and since he's chosen not to update the list with new sites, when the old ones go defunct, the script stops working.

---

### Possible Solutions

1. The closest you're going to get is specifying gnu as the only option
   in the --findsites option, i.e. `--findsites=gnu`, but please note
   that you cannot add distribution specific repositories, because the
   perl script only understands the items available in the SITELIST
   array.
2. After digging around, I found the SITELIST array: (Lines 2,380 - 2388 of the configure/toast script):

   `my(@sites) =
   (
   "freshmeat" => "http://freshmeat.net/projects/$lcname",
   "googlecode" => "http://code.google.com/p/$lcname/downloads/list",
   "sourceforge" => "http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/" .
       "download.sourceforge.net/pub/sourceforge/$sfname/",
   "gnu" => "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/$lcname/",
   "cpan" => "http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/module/$perlname",
   );`

You could remove freshmeat from this array, but then you need to update the handler (Lines 2,400 -2,494), remove the freshmeat search, and add search parsings for each repository type you want to add... This approach is BAD, because URL's cannot be guaranteed static, yet that array is a set of static strings.

---

**5 Point Question**:  It used to install packages.
**10 Point Question**(hunch): Now that bitrot set in, and I realize that URL's can change structure, or die, the moral is: A programmer shouldn't rely on searching a string when he can't be in charge of the way the string is formatted.

Comment: Thank you, if the script every fails me I will have to learn some bsaic Perl. This script is just more than useful for me.

Comment: May I ask what distribution you're on?  I may have a solution...

Comment: @ eyoung100 I am using toast on Ubuntu, Fedora and CentOS.

Comment: @CodeClown Can you create a chroot??

Comment: @ eyoung100: Yes that is possible.

Comment: Have a look at [The Gentoo Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64) - Assuming Amd64, and follow all but the last 2 Steps.  Not configuring a bootloader will leave the chroot intact, and you'll always have root access.  The chrot contains portage.  All packages on an entire Gentoo system are built from portage, and all packages are source.

Comment: Ah thank you! That is an interesting approach, will give it a try sometime soon.